# How to change response of HTTPS request, or force a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: redirect, https, isp

I work for an ISP.  We implemented a system where if a subscriber runs out of money in his account, then his browser will only show a specific HTML page. From page subscriber could be found, for whatever reason he disconnected from Internet.

If the browser makes a request to HTTP, then it is not a problem. However, if a request is made by HTTPS, then it's not clear how to replace this page, because when configuring Nginx with his certificate the browser gives certificate errors and our web page does not display.  A redirect to HTTP also fails because the browser has not yet established a secure connection.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. That is the specific purpose of SSL. If you could do that and let believe your customer's browser that the website he expects is the real one then you would have broken the very fundation of SSL.

The only thing you can do is for a layer4 redirection to another website first, (then eventually redirect via a HTTP 301 answer), but you will always get an alert from the browser.

Comment: Or, block all outbound requests on port 443.  When the customer pays, they can get their HTTPS back.